# Swift DidSelectRowAt not firing

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a project with a few different VCs...two of them have TableViews

The first one works perfectly fine, I have a custom view in there etc.

The second one is also custom and it fill the information in just fine, but unlike the first one...I cannot tap on it to segue to the next VC

I have the Delegate and DataSource set up properly. I have another VC on my project with a tableview and it works just fine. The first thing I can think might be preventing it from working is a UILabel takes up 90% of the cell, but I don't think that is it because I made the label small and tried tapping then and it still wouldn't hit the breakpoint.

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let row = indexPath.row

    selectedService = serviceArray[row].serviceID! as String

    if selectedService != "" {

      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromCardDetailsToEditService", sender: self)

    }
  }
```

I do not know if it matters BUT...the VC that I am on is in a Tab Bar Controller and a Nav Bar Controller. Does it matter for the performSegue that I am in a Tab Bar? And that this button is not a tab bar item?

Comment: Are you sure the second VC is set as the data source and delegate of the table view?

Comment: So in the VC that has the TableView (the VC I am trying to leave) I put in the ViewDidLoad... self.tableView.delegate = self, and self.tableView.dataSource = self ...That is where I have it on the other VC with a tableView....do I need to move those 2 lines to the custom TableViewCell Class?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with table view cells. That basically means that the problem is not because you did not set the delegate.

Comment: @Sweeper if this helps...I am able to get it to fire IF I use two fingers...but I don't know why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you have any `GestureRecognizer` on your `UIViewController` because in case of `GestureRecognizer` `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` does not called.

Comment: Yes I do, I was not aware that interrupted didSelectRowAt

Comment: Then please remove that GestureRecognizer for your UIVIewController and  then try once again and check  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) will be called or not.

Comment: yes that solved it, but ideally I would like to have both...Im using that gesture recognizer to dismiss the keyboard

Comment: To dismiss keyboard you can touch events.

Answer (score 5):

I figured out how to have my Gesture Recognizer AND the didSelectRowAt.

```
 let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CardDetailsViewController.dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

This is what I already had, which was causing conflict.

To fix it, this simple line let me dismiss the keyboard AND be able to tap on my cells.

```
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```