# How to redirect to another view controller when click on TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I can't figure why it can't redirect to another View Controller when I click on a `TableViewCell`

**FirstViewController** is the view controller that contains the tableView

**SecondViewController** is my desination

**What I already done:**

1) I embedded `FirstViewController` in a `NavigationController` in `StoryBoard`

2) I already set up show segue from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController`, and already set the segue identifier to "GoToSecondViewController"

Of course in order for me to show the data in the tableViewCell I have this 2 function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.myCell.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCellClass
        cell.myCellList = self.myCell[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

3) In `FirstViewController`, I already try for below 2 solution:

**First solution:**

- I call `performSegue` in `didSelectRowAt` function

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToSecondViewController", sender: self)    
  }
  ```

**Second solution:**

- I use navigationController?.pushViewController in `didSelectRowAt` function

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

      let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

  }
  ```

Above 2 solution I tried, but didn't produce any result. After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868064/swift-didselectrowat-not-firing), I even disable my `gestureRecognizer` in `FirstViewController`, still cant redirect to `SecondViewController`

So I finally just wanna to print out the value by this,but also no value printing out in console:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("section: \(indexPath.section)")
        print("row: \(indexPath.row)")
    }
```

That all I tried in order to redirect to another view controller when click on tableViewCell, but still not working.What I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure it out,I need to check the `Single Selection` option for `TableView` in StoryBoard.

Like this:

[image]

Previously I set the Selection to No Selection.Therefore causing the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in viewDidLoad

```
 tableview.delegate = self
```

Comment: I already have this line of code in my `viewDidLoad`.I already have delegate and datasource in my viewDidLoad

Comment: I think you adding a gesture above the tableview ?, Do you scroll the table like usualy ? or adding a gesture above tableCell

Comment: I already disable the gesture at the above..no more gestureRecognizer..I delete the code...and yes,I can scroll the tableView normally

Comment: put this line in cellForRow  cell.userInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: I put this line to cellForRowAt..but still no response.